# Uniformly sample a point per polytope

Tags: computational-geometry, probability

- I want to uniformly sample a point within each of $10^5$ convex polytopes in each iteration of a solver.
- The polytopes in one iteration are completely different from the polytopes in another iteration.
- The dimension of the space is about 15.
- The vertices of each polytopes are known.
- I only want one point per polytope.

Hit and run sampling would take quite a lot of steps to converge to a uniform distribution.

Triangulating each polytope to simplex can work. But doing that in high dimension seems tedious (at a quick glance.)

Are there other methods to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You might find the minimal enclosing sphere (via linear programming) and then sample uniformly in the sphere until a point is inside the polytope.

Comment: Don't need linear programming to do that if I just want a rough sphere centered at average of vertices. If the polytope is thin, it will take many trials to find a point within the polytope. The situation gets worse when the dimension increases.

Comment: I would think diffusion over the barycentric coordinate is faster than that if the generation of random number is the bottleneck. Maybe I can use the pdf of exponential distribution to speed up the rate of diffusion, as in sampling within a simplex:https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3227/uniform-sampling-from-a-simplex

Comment: Yes, the enclosing sphere is only useful if your polytopes are "round."

Comment: See the answers to this MO question: [Uniformly Sampling from Convex Polytopes](https://mathoverflow.net/q/9854/6094).

Comment: But I'm sure it's no more difficult to find an enclosing ellipsoid than it is to find an enclosing sphere.